# Spring JDBCTemplate is taking too long to execute the oracle update query

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I and executing an ORACLE update query with updates 16 columns of a single table. When I execute the query on my  sql developer. It gets executed pretty fast and I get the message

> Task completed in 0.003 seconds

However when I execute the same query using jdbc template It is taking 7-8 seconds to execute. The following is my java code.

```
long invFileInfoUpdateStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
String updateSql = "UPDATE DB_REPO.INV_INFO SET FILE_STATUS = ?,FILE_TYPE = ?,FILE_SYSTEM_NAME=?,FILE_DOC_NO=?, FILE_PAGES=?,FILE_EST_CHARS_PER_PAGE=?, FILE_TOTAL_CHARS=?, FILE_COMMENTS=?, FILE_UPDATED_BY=?, FILE_LAST_UPDT_DT= SYSDATE , FILE_USER_ID=?, FILE_STAMP_DT=TO_DATE(?, 'MM-dd-yyyy'), FILE_DUMP_DT=TO_DATE(?, 'MM-dd-yyyy'), FILE_CODE=?, FILE_Z_CODE=?,IS_RELATED_FILE=?,FILE_ONLINE_STATUS=?,FILE_SOURCE_TYPE=?,FILE_PUB_STATUS=?,FILE_UPDATE_STATUS=? WHERE FILE_INODE=?";
jdbcTemplate.update(updateSql,fileStatus,fileType,systemName,docNumber,numberOfPages,estimatedCharsPage,estimatedCharactersPerFile,comments,lastUpdatedBy,userId,stampDate,dumpDate,code,ZCode,isRelatedFILE,onlineFile,sourceType,documentPublicationStatus,status,fileInode);
long invFileInfoUpdateEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
iSmLog.info("Total time taken by the  update : " + (invFileInfoUpdateEndTime - invFileInfoUpdateStartTime)  + "milli-seconds");
```

The following I get in my logs:

> Total time taken by the  update : 8799milli-seconds

**The time gap is considerable. Why is it so long to execute? What can I do to optimize the performance of this query ?**

**EDIT:**

The following is the way I created my database connection using applicationContext-framework.xml

```
<bean id="webLogicXADataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="#[csa.db.driver]" />
        <property name="url" value="#[csa.db.url]" />
        <property name="username" value="#[csa.db.usernameInvoice]" />
        <property name="password" value="#[csa.db.passwordInvoice]" />
</bean>
```

**APPLOGS:**

[image]

Attached a screenshot. My method consists of 12 dml statements(insert update delete). Only the mentioned query(2nd in the screen shot) is taking so long to execute

Comment: Are you creating connection pools?

Comment: I just edited my question. I am creating a single connection

Comment: If you do another update immediately after, does this also take a long time?

Comment: No I have attached a pic of logs in  the original ques please refer

Comment: Strange.  Any triggers?

Comment: Yes there is a trigger but that is on insert only and I am simply firing an update query on that table

Comment: Use a proper connection pool... `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't intended for production use. And you are now basically comparing apples with oranges. The time taken most of it goes to establishing a connection with the database, each query will result in closing the connection and opening a new one. (Or if you are lucky and use managed transaction the connection might be reused). Use a proper connection pool that has connections ready for use. That is also what happens when you use sql developer as a connection is already established.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Can you please help me out How can I create reusable connections by explaining it . or else by some documentation?

Comment: and if that would have been the reason why only a particular query will take so long rest are getting executed pretty fast

Comment: As stated that depends if you use spring managed transaction or not. If so the connection could be created with the first query, and reused for the others. Those not taking a hit. As stated use a proper connection pool like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). The [`DriverManagerDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) is not a connection pool (as clearly stated by the documentation).

Comment: Another note is that the query in sql developer is just a query it isn't committed. Which in turn might (depending on yuor setup but there is too little information about that) happen with the jdbc tempalte. it actually commits and persists the things in the database. While the on in sql developer (without a commit) doesn't.